# How do I validate data with differing nested $schema values with ajv?

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator, ajv

I am trying to validate data with different nested `$schema` values against a schema that allows it, but it doesn't correctly validate the nested objects with the correct sub schema.

Here's a simplified example:

```js
const ajv = new Ajv();

const mainSchema = {
  $id: "mainSchema",
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    foo: {
      anyOf: [{ $ref: "intSchema" }, { $ref: "strSchema" }],
    },
  },
};
const intSchema = {
  $id: "intSchema",
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    value: {
      type: "integer",
    },
  },
};
const strSchema = {
  $id: "strSchema",
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    value: {
      type: "string",
    },
  },
};

const dataA = {
  $schema: "mainSchema",
  foo: {
    $schema: "intSchema",
    value: 42,
  },
};

const dataB = {
  $schema: "mainSchema",
  foo: {
    $schema: "strSchema",
    value: 1,
  },
};

const dataC = {
  $schema: "mainSchema",
  foo: {
    $schema: "unknownSchema",
    value: false,
  },
};

ajv.addSchema([intSchema, strSchema]);
const validate = ajv.compile(mainSchema);
console.log(validate(dataA)); // true
console.log(validate(dataB)); // true
console.log(validate(dataC)); // false
```

Both `dataA` and `dataB` return `true` when I was expecting `validate(dataB)` to return false. I thought it would use the `$schema` value from the data to validate the object against the added schema with the corresponding `$id`.

I could make a function that steps through each data object and uses the `$id` property to validate it against the corresponding schema if that's the only way to accomplish this, but I assumed ajv should handle it.

Comment: Maybe I could apply the subschemas using some of the conditional examples in the JSON Schema documentation: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html#implication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Jeremy Fiel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8564731/jeremy-fiel) pointed out, the validator ignores the `$schema` property in the nested data type (it didn't even have an issue with an undefined `$schema` being used). I played with the idea of using conditionals to pick what type of subschema to apply, but it seemed more straightforward to add validation rules to the `$schema` property itself.

```js
const ajv = new Ajv();

const mainSchema = {
  $id: "mainSchema",
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    foo: {
      anyOf: [{ $ref: "intSchema" }, { $ref: "strSchema" }],
    },
  },
};
const intSchema = {
  $id: "intSchema",
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    $schema: {
      const: "intSchema",
    },
    value: {
      type: "integer",
    },
  },
};
const strSchema = {
  $id: "strSchema",
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    $schema: {
      const: "strSchema",
    },
    value: {
      type: "string",
    },
  },
};

const dataA = {
  $schema: "mainSchema",
  foo: {
    $schema: "intSchema",
    value: 42,
  },
};

const dataB = {
  $schema: "mainSchema",
  foo: {
    $schema: "strSchema",
    value: 1,
  },
};

const dataC = {
  $schema: "mainSchema",
  foo: {
    $schema: "unknownSchema",
    value: false,
  },
};
ajv.addSchema([intSchema, strSchema]);
const validate = ajv.compile(mainSchema);
console.log(validate(dataA)); // true
console.log(validate(dataB)); // false
console.log(validate(dataC)); // false
```

The main downside to this strategy is that the `$schema` property loses some flexibility and it is a bit redundant.

Comment: There's a misunderstanding with the way you are using the `$schema` keyword. It's irrelevant if you don't have a custom JSON Schema vocabulary to load into the implementation for validation. It sounds like what you really want to do is define which schema should be applied at runtime. When using JSON Schema, the purpose of the `$schema` keyword is to define the dialect to be used for validation. Some of the keywords are unsupported in previous versions and some behaviors have changed over time. The keyword is not to be used for indicating which schema should be applied to a data instance.

Comment: if you don't specify the JSON Schema draft in the root schema, assuming you are using Ajv 8+, it will default to `draft-07`.  this is equivalent to `{ "$id": "mainSchema","$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#"}`

Comment: I left it out for simplification, but I'm using `"$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema"`

Comment: It isn't exactly that I want it to be applied at runtime; there's a finite set of which types it could be, but there is more than one possible type of object that could be in there with a corresponding `$schema`.

Comment: if you aren't using keywords specific to 2020-12, I would recommend using draft-07.  Ajv doesn't completely support 2020-12, and you didn't post your import statement, but you need to make sure you are importing `const ajv = require('ajv/dist/2020')` to use the 2020-12 metaschema.

Comment: I am using the formats and I am using `ajv/dist/2020`, but that doesn't seem to impact this issue from the simplified tests I've put together.

Comment: Formats are not used for validation. They are only an annotation which means informational use only

Answer (score 1):

`dataB` is `true` because it satisfies `anyOf` the schemas you've defined. The validator does not consider the use of `$schema` to identify which `$id` shall be used to validate against. It only knows of the schemas you've loaded into the registry with the `addSchema` method.

Your use of `$schema` in the data instance is ignored because you have not constrained that property in the schema definitions. Typically, you only use `$schema` in the schema itself, not the instance. But this is a hot topic of debate. It's not defined in the JSON Schema specification.

What I mean by *not constrained* is shown in the following schema, which would invalidate all of your schemas with the use of `$schema` as an additional property in your instance.

```js
const mainSchema = {
  $id: "mainSchema",
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    foo: {
      anyOf: [{ $ref: "intSchema" }, { $ref: "strSchema" }],
    },
  },
};
const intSchema = {
  $id: "intSchema",
  type: "object",
  additionalProperties: false,
  properties: {
    value: {
      type: "integer",
    },
  },
};
const strSchema = {
  $id: "strSchema",
  type: "object",
  additionalProperties: false,
  properties: {
    value: {
      type: "string",
    },
  },
};
```

For `anyOf`, the instance is considered valid if at least one of the schemas returns a `true` result. Try using `oneOf` and you should have your expected results.

Comment: `oneOf` has the same result because one of the schemas does validate since it isn't considering the `$schema` value.

Comment: For the sake of the example if your schema was actually only one property with the name `value` then yes this example would fail but I assume that your schema has a lot more properties that don't contain the same value.

Comment: In my actual application, it isn't too different. All of the schemas have the same property names but different validations for each $schema, so it's possible more than one would apply.

Comment: You can simplify your schema with the following   `{ "properties": {"foo": { "properties": { "value":{ "anyOf": [ { "title": "intschema","type": "string"}, { "title": "string schema",type": integer"}]}}}}`

Comment: Opps, I switched the titles.  Sorry, on my phone replying

Comment: Yeah, that’s pretty close to the solution I posted. Both have the downside of not having the flexibility of the $schema uri. I could get close with some regex patterns.

Comment: Would be good to reference this discussion which explains why JSON Schema can't specify `$schema`'s use in instances.  https://github.com/orgs/json-schema-org/discussions/473